# Resizing a container with an iframe by clicking a button

Tags: javascript, html, css, onclick, resize

The question is pretty much in the title. Here's what I have:

JS

```
    function zoomvid() {
    document.getElementsById('containervid').height="337.5px"; 
    document.getElementsById('containervid').width="500px";
}

function unzoomvid() {
    document.getElementsById('containervid').height="202.5px"; 
    document.getElementsById('containervid').width="300px";
}

function resetsize() {
    document.getElementsById('containervid').height="270px"; 
    document.getElementsById('containervid').width="400px";
}
```

[EDIT] I tried doing this. 0 effect.

```
function resizing() {
var plus = document.getElementById("zoom");
var moins = document.getElementById("unzoom");
var normal = document.getElementById("reset");

var objet = document.getElementById("containervid");

if(plus) {
    objet.style.height = "337.5px";
    objet.style.width = "500px";
}

if(moins) {
    objet.style.height = "202.5px";
    objet.style.width = "300px";
}

if(normal) {
        objet.style.height = "270px";
        objet.style.width = "400px";
    }
};
```

of course when doing this I put `onclick="resizing()"` to all of my buttons.

CSS

```
.containervid {
    position: absolute;
    top: 120px;
    width: 400px;
    height: 270px;
    background-color: black;
}

#iframevid {
    position: absolute;
    align-self: baseline;
    padding-bottom: 0;
    width: inherit;
    height: 230px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.containervid > button {
    border-radius: 15px;
    background-color: white;
    font-family: monospace;
    font-weight: 700;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 11px;
    outline: none;
    border-style: none;
    color: rgb(29, 29, 29);
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="containervid" id="containervid">
            <iframe id="iframevid" 
             frameborder="0" 
             type="text/html" 
             src="https://www.dailymotion.com/embed/video/x3p85xq" allowfullscreen > 
            </iframe>
            <button id="zoom" onclick="zoomvid()">+</button> 
            <button id="unzoom" onclick="unzoomvid()">-</button> 
            <button id="reset" onclick="resetsize()">reset</button> 
        </div>
```

I know for a fact that my js is wrong because 1. dev console says it on inspect element 2. I really, really suck at js. Any help please?
Unzoom is supposed to, well, shrink, and zoom the opposite while resetsize, well... resets the size.

Comment: you starting an `if` statement but with no rules/terms to it. you also need to declare rules to an if statement that can either be `true` or `false`.

Comment: also you calling getElementById but trying to adress a class. Eitehr use an ID within your HTML or use querySelector(".class")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with JQuery;

```
$('button').click(function() {
var plus = document.getElementById("zoom");
var moins = document.getElementById("unzoom");
var normal = document.getElementById("reset");

var objet = document.getElementById("containervid");

if(this==plus) {
    objet.style.height = "337.5px";
    objet.style.width = "500px";
}

if(this==moins) {
    objet.style.height = "202.5px";
    objet.style.width = "300px";
}

if(this==normal) {
        objet.style.height = "270px";
        objet.style.width = "400px";
    }
});
```

Or you can do it with JS like this;

```
function zoomvid() {
document.getElementById('containervid').style.height="337.5px"; 
document.getElementById('containervid').style.width="500px";
}

function unzoomvid() { 
document.getElementById('containervid').style.height="202.5px"; 
document.getElementById('containervid').style.width="300px";
}

function resetsize() {
document.getElementById('containervid').style.height="270px"; 
document.getElementById('containervid').style.width="400px";
}
```

In your first code section, you have written `getElementsById`. This should be `getElementById` and add `().style.height`

And second code section, if you want to know which button was click then better way is using JQuery.

Here is the [JS version](https://codepen.io/gokselozr/pen/JjRbqmL)

Here is the [JQuery](https://codepen.io/gokselozr/pen/gOwLJBJ)

Comment: add the HTML and CSS code to it, you'll see that it wont work. He has fundemental coding issues going far beyond your solution. he has no ID's within HTML or CSS he uses classes. Therefor `getElementByID` cant work as he need `querySelector('.class')`

Comment: Oh I missed that he declared a class and ID. I stand corrected.

Answer (score 0):

`document.getElementsByID('containervid').height = "337.5px";` has a spelling error. Its called `getElementById`. Just a single element as an ID has to be unique and there cant be multiple ones. Which also makes it the wrong selector as you using a classnot an ID. Yo need to use `querySelector('.containervid')`. Then th next mistake is, that you missing the .style between your selector and the height. So it should be:

`document.querySelector('.containervid').style.height = "337.5px";`

the same error continues in every single line.

```js
function zoomvid() {
  document.querySelector('.containervid').style.height = "337.5px";
  document.querySelector('.containervid').style.width = "500px";
}

function unzoomvid() {
  document.querySelector('.containervid').style.height = "202.5px";
  document.querySelector('.containervid').style.width = "300px";
}

function resetsize() {
  document.querySelector('.containervid').style.height = "270px";
  document.querySelector('.containervid').style.width = "400px";
}
```

```css
.containervid {
  position: absolute;
  top: 120px;
  width: 400px;
  height: 270px;
  background-color: black;
}

#iframevid {
  position: absolute;
  align-self: baseline;
  padding-bottom: 0;
  width: inherit;
  height: 230px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.containervid>button {
  border-radius: 15px;
  background-color: white;
  font-family: monospace;
  font-weight: 700;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 11px;
  outline: none;
  border-style: none;
  color: rgb(29, 29, 29);
}
```

```html
<div class="containervid" id="containervid">
  <iframe id="iframevid" frameborder="0" type="text/html" src="https://www.dailymotion.com/embed/video/x3p85xq" allowfullscreen> 
            </iframe>
  <button id="zoom" onclick="zoomvid()">+</button>
  <button id="unzoom" onclick="unzoomvid()">-</button>
  <button id="reset" onclick="resetsize()">reset</button>
</div>
```